# How to I add a number to every column

Tags: r

This is a very basic question however for some reason I can't seem to figure it out.

I currently have data structured like this as a result of the function na.locf in R

```
Date        Data
1/1/2019    2.5
1/2/2019    3
1/3/2019    1.75
```

I'd simply like to add a number (e.g: 10) to each instance of data resulting in a table like this

```
Date        Data
1/1/2019    12.5
1/2/2019    13
1/3/2019    11.75
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just do `df1$Data <- df1$Data + 10`

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. That resulted in the non-numeric argument to binary operator error.

Comment: then, it must be bcz you have non-numeric columns

Comment: Try `as.numeric(as.character(df1$Data)) + 10`

Comment: Questions should have reproducible input.  Please show the output of `dput(x)` where `x` is the data shown in the question.  this should be shown by editting the question, not in a comment.

Comment: @akrun that worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df1$Data <- df1$Data + 10
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried.

That resulted in the non-numeric argument to binary operator error.

I then tried to convert it to numeric to solve the issue. However no luck